# Passing a variable to the Child Component to use as a data filter

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have 2 components:

- navbar - with a button that changes the label when clicked and returns to the default value when clicked again
- (table)view - displaying results

Project structure:

```html
<div class="home">
  <side-panel></side-panel>
  <div>
    <navbar></navbar>
    <table-view></table-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent Component:

```
export class NavbarComponent {
  showCompleted: boolean = true;

  constructor() {}

  onClick() {
    this.showCompleted = !this.showCompleted;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button (click)="onClick()" mat-button>{{ showCompleted ? 'Hide Completed' : 'Show Completed' }}</button>
</div>
```

Child Component:

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private subscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  columns: string[] = ['name', 'description', 'isCompleted'];
  results: DisplayableResult[] = [];
  @Input() showCompleted: boolean = true;

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service
      .getResultGet(1)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.subscribe$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: Result) => {
          const displayableResult: DisplayableResult = {
            name: res.name,
            description: res.description,
            isCompleted: res.isCompleted,
          } as DisplayableResult;

          this.results.push(displayableResult);
          this.refreshResult();
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      });
  }

  refreshResult() {
    this.results = [...this.results];
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscribe$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="results">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.description }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="isCompleted">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Completed</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="element.isCompleted"></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns"></tr>
</table>
```

I want to pass a boolean property from ParentComponent and display the results based on it in ChildComponent.

With the default value, all results should be displayed, after pressing the button, the button label changes and the results should refresh according to the set filter - boolean variable.

Thanks everyone who can help me.

I am still learning basics of Angular.

Comment: You don't seem to call the child component in the parent's template. Passing data from parent to child is easy in Angular by using the @Input directives. How do you render the child component inside the parent component?

Comment: @VasilisG.   I have  updated post with project structure.
So I click button on NavBar Component, button's label changes and result should be filtered and loaded in Table-view Component.

Answer (score 1):

The nav and view components are siblings. This is not a parent child relationship.

You really have a few options,

1. Put the view component inside the nav component so that you can just pass `showCompleted` into the input of the view component (I don't think this is what you want)
2. Put the `showCompleted` in the true parent component (where nav and view are shown) and add an `@Output` from the nav component to notify its parent that the button was clicked and change `showCompleted` in it's handler.
3. Use a tiny service with a subject or signal that holds the `showCompleted` state and inject it into both the nav and view components.

Personally, I would probably go with option #2 unless there is more state that you need to share between the two components, then I would go with #3.